# Не получается простенький код в python

Tags: python

Не могу найти ошибку! Помогите, пожалуйста.
Код:

```
a = input('делимое')
b = input('делитель')  
print('Ответ: {:.2%}'.format(a/b))
```

Comment: Пытались ли вы исполнить код в вопросе? Что вы ожидали получить? Что получается вместо этого—опишите подробно. Если вы видите ошибки в консоле, скопируйте их в вопрос как есть (полный traceback). Какая у вас версия Питона? ОСь?

Answer (score 4):

Функция `input()` возвращает строки, а не числа. Перед делением нужно их преобразовывать в числа, например так:

```
a = int(input('делимое'))
b = int(input('делитель'))
...
```

если нужны целые числа, или

```
a = float(input('делимое'))
b = float(input('делитель'))
...
```

если нужны числа с плавающей точкой.

В следующий раз, когда будете задавать вопрос по ошибке, указывайте ошибку в тексте вопроса. В данном случае это не критично, т.к. кода мало, но вообще лучше всегда указывать.

Comment: @jfs, интересно, получается, что `input()` в Python2 более интеллектуальный, чем в Python3.

Comment: [неудачно комментарий обновил] Если рассматривать пример как Питон 2 код, тогда код уже может работать как есть (хотя лучше явно `float(raw_input())` использовать). Может OP не знает, что `1/2==0` в Питоне 2 или как `%` формат работает. Поделитесь оборудованием по чтению мыслей ;)

Comment: @jfs, ну, по крайней мере `print` он использует как в Python3, хотя это еще ни о чем не говорит. Если исходить из того, что это Python3, то ошибка все-таки в том, что входные данные не преобразовываются в числа. Хотя может быть это все-таки Python2, и автор действительно не ожидал увидеть ответ в процентах.